# Use circular queue and Iterators to automatically wrap

Tags: c++

The below code snippet traverses a vector and prints the difference between the current and the previous value in the array. It works.
This code loops in an infinte for loop

```
    start = 60;
    iterator = 0;
    std::vector<ushort> m_xPos(600,0); // consists of 600 elements with default 0.

    for ( ;; ) {
        //If we are at the end of the path vector, we need to reset our iterators
        if ( start+iterator) >= m_xPos.size() ) {
            start = 0;
            iterator = 0;
            std::cout << m_xPos.at(0) - m_xPos.at(m_xPos.size() - 1);
        } 
        else {
            std::cout <<  m_xPos.at(start+iterator) - m_xPos.at(start+iterator-(ushort)1);
        }
        iterator++;

    }
```

How can I achieve the same thing using

1. std::vec::iterator?
2. circular Queue?
3. Any other simpler method?

Comment: @Drax corrected

Answer (score 0):

You just need something that assigns `m_xPos.begin()` when the iterator gets to `m_xPos.end()`

```
auto circularNext = [&m_xPos](auto it) { ++it; return (it == m_xPos.end()) ? m_xPos.begin() : it; };
for (auto first = m_xPos.begin() + 59, second = m_xPos.begin() + 60; ; first = circularNext(first), second = circularNext(second)) {
    std::cout << *second - *first;
}
```